# Get elements from array where date is today

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdate

I have an array of objects where a property is date of type NSDate. The array includes future days and past days.

I want to get an array of elements from that array that only includes dates that are in today, not the last 24 hours.

I ordered the elements by descending (new to old):

```
allDashboards.sortInPlace({ $0.date!.compare($1.date!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
```

I tried to do a for loop, check if date is yesterday and cut the array there, but it doesn't work as it may be no element with a yesterdays date:

```
    for dash in allDashboards {

        if (NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInYesterday(dash.date!)) {
            print(i)
            allDashboards.removeRange(Range.init(start: 0, end: i))
            break
        }

        i += 1
    }
```

Is there a method to see if date is past a day instead of if the date is part of that day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner:

```
let todayDashboards = allDashboards.filter { NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInToday($0.date!) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSDateComponents` to create the dates which represent the start and end of your acceptable range. These can be anything you want.

Once you have those dates, you can create an `NSPredicate` which matches dates `>` the start and `<` the end dates. This will generate a filtered array for you.

You could use `isDateInToday` to filter the content too.

What you must not do is to iterate the array and mutate it at the same time, which is what your current code does with `allDashboards.removeRange` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all dates which are today with the `filter` function and `isDateInToday` of `NSCalendar`

```
let filteredDashboards = allDashboards.filter{ NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInToday($0.date!) }
```